# How can I find data but ignore key data by nodejs express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

How can I find data but ignore key data by nodejs express and monogodb
[image]

This is my code:

```
exports.getFileFromFolder = async (req, res, next) => {
  const storage = await Proof.find({ });
  if (!storage) {
    return next(new Error("404 not found"));
  }
  res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    storage,
  });
};
```

Comment: Remove the unwanted keys from the document using `delete`, or use [`Proof.find().select()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-select).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `select` method for projection.

```
  const storage = await Proof.find().select('name mimeType size parentId');
```